# How can I move an embedded document value to the main document in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

If I wanted to move the "Artist" field from Details into the main Document with songID and Title, how would I do this? I want to keep the values the same

```
{
    SongId: 1,
    title: "Girls Just Wanna Have Fun",
    Details: {"Artist":"Cyndi Lauper", "Album":"example","ReleaseYear": 1983}
  },
```

I've looked into $unset, $pull and a few others but none of them seem to do what I need. Thank You!

Comment: You can do that in an _update_ operation using the [$rename](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/#mongodb-update-up.-rename) update operator.

Comment: Posted answer according to @prasad_ solution

Answer (score 0):

```
db.test.update(   
  {'SongId': 1 },   
  {$rename: { 'Details.Artist': 'Artist'} }
)
```